# Two gradients with two distinct sections with just one div element

Tags: html, css, gradient

I was wondering if it is possible to create a background effect like in the image below **using just one div**.

I know how to achieve it with two divs, but my situation would make it really easy if it could be done in one div (maybe using :after ???). The code for the gradients is:

```
.bg-green {
    background-image: linear-gradient(-180deg, #95D428 0%, #20560B 100%);
}

.bg-red {
    background-image: linear-gradient(-180deg, #F5515F 0%, #8E0A1E 100%; 
}
```

[image]

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this effect, but you will need to set overflow hidden on the div and to set the background in a after pseudo class

```css
.test {
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    border: solid 1px black;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.test:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 160%;
    height: 160%;
    top: -30%;
    left: -30%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(-210deg, #95D428 0%, #20560B 100%), linear-gradient(-210deg, #F5515F 0%, #8E0A1E 100%);
    background-position: top left, top right;
    background-size: 50% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

The after is rotated to get the inclined separation. The dimensions need to be bigger so as not to show missing corners.

And then, you assign the 2 linear gradients as 2 separate background-images,inclined an additional 30deg to compensate for the base inclination

Comment: Simple but effective.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible using a single `div` with a :pseudo-element.

What you could do is add the second `linear-gradient` to its `:after` :pseudo-element. Notice the use of `rgba(r, b, g, a)` instead of hex colors. This way you could control the opacity of the second `linear-gradient` by changing its alpha value.

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: linear-gradient(110deg, #5EDC29 45%, #FF0058 45%, #FF0058 100%);
  z-index: -1;
}
div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-180deg, transparent 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.6) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

If you want the exact same gradient colors that you've posted in your question, you'll need `clipPath`.

```css
body {
  background: #222222;
  margin: 0;
}
.bg {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background: linear-gradient(-180deg, #F5515F 0%, #8E0A1E 100%);
}
.bg-2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-180deg, #95D428 0%, #20560B 100%);
}
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="300">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="shape">
      <path d="M300,0 L501,0 L501,301 L175,301z" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <foreignObject clip-path="url(#shape)" width="500" height="300">
    <div class="bg"></div>
  </foreignObject>
</svg>
<div class="bg-2"></div>
```

Comment: You're just splitting the div for colors, the OP has an additional gradient for the colors.

Comment: This is closer, but doesn't really answer my question. I still want to keep the gradients as posted in my question, not just 2 plain colors.

Comment: @chipChocolate.py yeah exactly :) 
I've posted the gradients I want to use in the question.

Comment: @chipChocolate.py Thanks, but that's not quite it. Should look exactly as the image I posted in the question.

Comment: @chipChocolate.py Getting closer, but it's not exactly the color vaulues I have choosen in the gradient. The gradient is not getting consistently darker in the same way for the red and green section. That's why an overlay probably won't work.

Comment: @Paul - Using CSS I don't think a solution other than an overlay is possible. You need `svg` to do it. I could give you an example using `svg` if you want.

Comment: @chipChocolate.py yeah I don't mind if the solution is SVG based. Thanks again for your support.

Comment: @Paul - Here, is an example that uses exact same colors as you have posted in your question. http://dabblet.com/gist/fd867a0ef68ce6f4e25b

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67964/discussion-between-chipchocolate-py-and-paul).

Comment: @chipChocolate.py awesome. not sure why, but it's only working in Firefox for me

Comment: @Paul - Please enter the chat room. We can't have long conversation in comments. It's against the rules.